# Docker daemon fails to start after updating

Tags: docker, centos

Last night my docker daemon got updated to version 18.09.0-ce-tp0, build 4bb0619 and from that time it fails to start. I was previously running docker without any problems.
OS: CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)
Error:

```
Aug 23 20:14:56 my-server-name polkitd[388]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:6198:531754 (system bus name :1.45 [/usr/bin/pkttyagent --notify-fd 5 --fallback], object path /org/freedesktop/Po
Aug 23 20:14:56 my-server-name polkitd[388]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:6198:531754 (system bus name :1.45, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UT
Aug 23 20:15:02 my-server-name polkitd[388]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:6210:532352 (system bus name :1.46 [/usr/bin/pkttyagent --notify-fd 5 --fallback], object path /org/freedesktop/Po
Aug 23 20:15:09 my-server-name containerd-offline-installer[6120]: failed to dial "/run/containerd/containerd.sock": context deadline exceeded
Aug 23 20:15:09 my-server-name systemd[1]: docker.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Aug 23 20:15:09 my-server-name systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
-- Subject: Unit docker.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit docker.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Aug 23 20:15:09 my-server-name systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
Aug 23 20:15:09 my-server-name systemd[1]: docker.service failed.
Aug 23 20:15:09 my-server-name polkitd[388]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:6210:532352 (system bus name :1.46, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UT
Aug 23 20:15:10 my-server-name systemd[1]: docker.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Aug 23 20:15:10 my-server-name systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
-- Subject: Unit docker.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit docker.service has begun starting up.
```

Just to make things clear, I'm starting with systemctl start docker (or docker.service) and e.g. docker ps returns Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

Any clue?

Comment: Did you check for more info in `journalctl`?

Comment: Sure - the error output is from journalctl

Comment: Also adding what I found in /var/log/messages: 
`Aug 23 06:43:04 my-server-name yum[16936]: Installed: containerd.io.x86_64 1.2.0-1.0.beta.0.el7
Aug 23 06:43:07 my-server-name yum[16936]: Installed: docker-ce-cli.x86_64 18.09.0.ce-0.0.tp0.el7`

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/1338855/160225

Answer (score 3):

I got a same issue by updating docker from version **18.06.1-ce, build e68fc7a** to version **18.09.0~ce~0.4.tp4-0~ubuntu** . 
My solution is :

1) Remove the **docker-ce**:

```
sudo apt-get remove docker-ce
```

2) remove dependency packages:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

3) check whether or not docker is removed (should see **docker command not found**):

```
docker -v
```

4) install the lower version of docker :

```
sudo apt-get install docker-ce=18.06.1~ce~3-0~ubuntu
```

5) check if the docker service is running:

```
sudo service docker status
```

It works for me. Hope the solution above can help you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just having the same issue. The only workaround I found is to kill containerd service and restart dockerd.

edit:
I resolved my issue, it seems to come from docker-ce-test and docker-ce-edge enabled

```
root@dkr:~# yum list docker-ce --showduplicates | sort -r
 * updates: ftp.pasteur.fr
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Installed Packages
 * extras: ftp.pasteur.fr
 * epel: ftp.plusline.net
docker-ce.x86_64         2:18.09.0.ce-0.4.tp4.el7               docker-ce-test
docker-ce.x86_64         2:18.09.0.ce-0.4.tp4.el7               @docker-ce-test
docker-ce.x86_64         2:18.09.0.ce-0.3.tp3.el7               docker-ce-test
docker-ce.x86_64         2:18.09.0.ce-0.0.tp0.el7               docker-ce-test
docker-ce.x86_64         18.06.1.ce-3.el7                       docker-ce-test
docker-ce.x86_64         18.06.1.ce-3.el7                       docker-ce-stable
docker-ce.x86_64         18.06.1.ce-3.el7                       docker-ce-edge
docker-ce.x86_64         18.06.1.ce-2.2.rc2.el7                 docker-ce-test
docker-ce.x86_64         18.06.1.ce-2.1.rc1.el7                 docker-ce-test
docker-ce.x86_64         18.06.0.ce-3.el7                       docker-ce-test
docker-ce.x86_64         18.06.0.ce-3.el7                       docker-ce-stable
docker-ce.x86_64         18.06.0.ce-3.el7                       docker-ce-edge
docker-ce.x86_64         18.06.0.ce-2.3.rc3.el7                 docker-ce-test
...
```

I removed all non stable versions:

```
sudo yum-config-manager --disable docker-ce-edge
sudo yum-config-manager --disable docker-ce-test
```

I removed and re-installed docker-ce (I am not sure that it is required):

```
yum remove docker-ce docker-ce-cli ; yum install docker-ce docker-ce-cli
```

Now I only have the stable version installed and everything works fine as before:

```
root@dkr:~# yum list docker-ce --showduplicates | sort -r
 * updates: ftp.pasteur.fr
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Installed Packages
 * extras: ftp.pasteur.fr
 * epel: mirror.speedpartner.de
docker-ce.x86_64            18.06.1.ce-3.el7                   docker-ce-stable
docker-ce.x86_64            18.06.1.ce-3.el7                   @docker-ce-stable
docker-ce.x86_64            18.06.0.ce-3.el7                   docker-ce-stable
docker-ce.x86_64            18.03.1.ce-1.el7.centos            docker-ce-stable
docker-ce.x86_64            18.03.0.ce-1.el7.centos            docker-ce-stable
docker-ce.x86_64            17.12.1.ce-1.el7.centos            docker-ce-stable
docker-ce.x86_64            17.12.0.ce-1.el7.centos            docker-ce-stable
docker-ce.x86_64            17.09.1.ce-1.el7.centos            docker-ce-stable
docker-ce.x86_64            17.09.0.ce-1.el7.centos            docker-ce-stable
docker-ce.x86_64            17.06.2.ce-1.el7.centos            docker-ce-stable
docker-ce.x86_64            17.06.1.ce-1.el7.centos            docker-ce-stable
docker-ce.x86_64            17.06.0.ce-1.el7.centos            docker-ce-stable
docker-ce.x86_64            17.03.2.ce-1.el7.centos            docker-ce-stable
docker-ce.x86_64            17.03.1.ce-1.el7.centos            docker-ce-stable
docker-ce.x86_64            17.03.0.ce-1.el7.centos            docker-ce-stable
```

Comment: This worked for me on CentOS 7! Thanks a lot. I don't know who downgraded your solution but it does work.

Comment: Let me add that I had to re-install docker-ce and docker-ce-cli to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for **Fedora 28** and the steps I took to resolve this.

As answered by @Alain docker-ce-test and docker-ce-edge enabled were the root causes of this issue. As there are many installations shown if those are enabled - one can install the wrong version accidentally during the installation phase.

#### To resolve:

First we remove this from the config manager

```
sudo dnf config-manager --set-disabled docker-ce-edge
sudo dnf config-manager --set-disabled docker-ce-test
```

Then remove the existing installation of docker that you have

`sudo dnf remove docker-ce docker-ce-cli`
or
`sudo dnf remove docker-ce docker-ce-<version>`

Install the version that you need from the stable builds

`dnf list docker-ce --showduplicates | sort -r`

```
Last metadata expiration check: 1:20:05 ago on Thu 29 Nov 2018 04:55:30 PM.
Installed Packages
docker-ce.x86_64               3:18.09.0-3.fc28                docker-ce-stable 
docker-ce.x86_64               18.06.1.ce-3.fc28               docker-ce-stable 
docker-ce.x86_64               18.06.1.ce-3.fc28               @docker-ce-stable
docker-ce.x86_64               18.06.1.ce-3.fc28               @docker-ce-stable
docker-ce.x86_64               18.06.0.ce-3.fc28               docker-ce-stable 
docker-ce.x86_64               18.03.1.ce-3.fc28               docker-ce-stable
```

We do not install the `docker-ce-cli` as per before as it will conflict during the transaction check if you tried to install a version over it.

e.g.

`sudo dnf install docker-ce-18.06.1.ce`

All should work now!